# The Peculiar Picker View/Function/Action Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

so today I've been working on a temperature converter app to reintroduce myself to the concepts I had learned so far in swift (I'm currently in the process of taking a class online) and I decided to add in a picker view. I don't have any bugs, but when I press the UIButton it doesn't respond to any of the if statements listed in my code - which are where all the temperature conversions are. So my question is, why is my button when pressed not converting the temperature entered in the text field, and how do I fix it? Thanks

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate   {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var conversionTypePickerView: UIPickerView!

    var temperatureConversions = ["°Farenheit-°Celcius", "°Celcius-°Farenheit", "°Farenheit-Kelvin", "Kelvin-°Farenheit", "°Celcius-Kelvin", "Kelvin-°Celcius"]
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return temperatureConversions.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return temperatureConversions[row]
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var newTemperatureLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func convertTemperatureButton(sender: UIButton) {
        var temperatureTextFieldConversion = temperatureTextField.text
        var temperatureTextFieldToDouble = Double((temperatureTextFieldConversion as NSString).doubleValue)

    // Converts number entered from textfield into double. 

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

            if temperatureConversions[row] == "°Farenheit-°Celcius"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\((temperatureTextFieldToDouble - 32) / 1.8)" + " °Celcius"

    //this is the first example of the if statements I mentioned above, other five are listed below

            }
            else{

            }

            if temperatureConversions[row] == "°Celcius-°Farenheit"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\(temperatureTextFieldToDouble * 1.8 + 32)" + " °Farenheit"


            }
            else{

            }

            if temperatureConversions[row] == "°Farenheit-Kelvin"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\(((temperatureTextFieldToDouble - 32) / 1.8) + 273.15)" + " Kelvin"

            }
            else{

            }

            if temperatureConversions[row] == "Kelvin-°Farenheit"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text =  "\((temperatureTextFieldToDouble - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32.00)" + " °Farenheit"

            }
            else {

            }

            if temperatureConversions[row] == "°Celcius-Kelvin"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\(temperatureTextFieldToDouble + 273.15)" + " Kelvin"

            }
            else{

            }

            if temperatureConversions[row] == "Kelvin-°Celcius"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\(temperatureTextFieldToDouble - 273.15)" + " °Celcius"

            }
            else{

            }


        }

        newTemperatureLabel.hidden = false
        temperatureTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        temperatureTextField.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If my answer solved your problem, please click on the checkmark next to it to turn it green.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is that your `pickerView:DidSelectRow:inComponent:` was inside of your `convertTemperatureButton:` function.  It needs to be a top level function in your `viewController` for it to be called.

Move `pickerView:DidSelectRow:inComponent:` to the top level, have it set a property `conversionType` in your `viewController`, and then have `convertTemperature` use that property:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate   {

    var conversionType = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        conversionType = temperatureConversions[0]
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var conversionTypePickerView: UIPickerView!

    var temperatureConversions = ["°Farenheit-°Celcius", "°Celcius-°Farenheit", "°Farenheit-Kelvin", "Kelvin-°Farenheit", "°Celcius-Kelvin", "Kelvin-°Celcius"]
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return temperatureConversions.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return temperatureConversions[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

        conversionType = temperatureConversions[row]
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var newTemperatureLabel: UILabel!

    // Converts number entered from textfield into double.
    @IBAction func convertTemperatureButton(sender: UIButton) {
        var temperatureTextFieldConversion = temperatureTextField.text
        var temperatureTextFieldToDouble = Double((temperatureTextFieldConversion as NSString).doubleValue)

        if conversionType == "°Farenheit-°Celcius"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\((temperatureTextFieldToDouble - 32) / 1.8)" + " °Celcius"

            //this is the first example of the if statements I mentioned above, other five are listed below

        }

        if conversionType == "°Celcius-°Farenheit"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\(temperatureTextFieldToDouble * 1.8 + 32)" + " °Farenheit"


        }

        if conversionType == "°Farenheit-Kelvin"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\(((temperatureTextFieldToDouble - 32) / 1.8) + 273.15)" + " Kelvin"

        }

        if conversionType == "Kelvin-°Farenheit"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text =  "\((temperatureTextFieldToDouble - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32.00)" + " °Farenheit"

        }

        if conversionType == "°Celcius-Kelvin"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\(temperatureTextFieldToDouble + 273.15)" + " Kelvin"

        }

        if conversionType == "Kelvin-°Celcius"{
            newTemperatureLabel.text = "\(temperatureTextFieldToDouble - 273.15)" + " °Celcius"

        }

        newTemperatureLabel.hidden = false
        temperatureTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        temperatureTextField.text = ""
    }
}
```